# Посоветуйте плагин галереи для custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Нужен плагин которой добавить галерею к кастомному типу записи. Типа как у `woocommerce` галерея товара.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший плагин для этого [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Позволяет добавлять различные типы полей к любым страницам/типам/etc.

В том числе там есть и галерея

Comment: поля уже есть, лень писать отдельно галерею. Попробуй с этим плагином

Comment: ну да , там нужно их заново создать и free версии нету галереи

Comment: @НикитаРязанов те нужно конкретно вьюху галереи сделать?

Comment: да, по аналогии woocommerce галерея товара

Comment: @НикитаРязанов а что мешает взять любой слайдер и прикрутить его к вашим кастомным полям?

Answer (score 0):

**CMB2**, в файле примеров (*example-functions.php*): 400 строка, file_list. Очень удобно делать галереи совместно со **slick**.